# Pop up modal with alert box notification

Tags: user-research, html, html5

So I have a pop-up modal which serves as subscription point and it has an email field, this email field has email validation and the error message is displayed in *alert box*.

My question, is it a good user experience to have a alert box in pop-up modal?

Note: I can't use html 5 email input for some reasons

Comment: Can't you run the validation messages next to the email field? I know this is possible with jquery: each key stroke triggers a check on the fields contents and can return an inline message based on wether the content of the field is a valid email address or not - You could also add in a check on focus change to give two different levels of inline alert: a low level inline alerts ("that's not quite an email address") on keystroke and a more urgent inline alert ("The email address you have entered is not valid") when the email field is de-focussed. Personally, I don't like alert boxes.

Answer (score 1):

An alert is not preferable since it indicates an error on "another layer", when it´s better to placer error messages **the closest you can to the source of the error** (in this case an input) to avoid the user the extra work of scanning where is the problem and perform 1 additional action (accept/close).

You could try **inline validation**, which will inform the user what's and where's the problem just after they fill the input.

[image]